# How to disassembly my driver?

Tags: windows-7, kernel, driver, windbg

I am trying kernel debugging using vmware and windbg.I have connected two OS and all symbols are loaded successfully.If I want to see my driver in memory how can I disassembly that?
I have tried lm commands and lmvm commands

```
kd> lmvm comint32
start    end        module name
88da9000 88daf000   comint32   (private pdb symbols)  C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\comint32.pdb\653387D894B4412FA9E30659E58DD47C1\comint32.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: comint32.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\comint32.sys
    Image name: comint32.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Apr 11 20:10:55 2013 (51677B3F)
    CheckSum:         0000CACF
    ImageSize:        00006000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x comint32!*` should dump all the symbols of the module along with their addresses in memory.

You can then either use the `u` command (with the name (e.g. `comint32!DriverEntry`) or the address of a function as a parameter) to disassemble into the main window or you can open the disassembly window and paste the name/address into it and browse the disassembled code there.

See your windbg reference for further details.

Comment: I have done this using u command i can able to see the disassembly of my driver if i want to print the dbgprint messages meand what i have to do

Comment: See [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10654782/968261), [2](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=295), [3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).